# adding slidetoggle to a panel switcher

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a slidetoggle function to a page, you can see the portion of the page i'm having problems with reproduced in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nickgardner/YYcH7/10/

I was able to get jquery slidetoggle working in isolation, but it doesn't work when I use it on the page. I'm not sure where the conflict is, any help is much appreciated.
thanks, Nick

http://jsfiddle.net/nickgardner/YYcH7/10/

```
$('#faq-1-1').click(function() {
    $('#faq-1-1-hide').slideToggle('slow', function() {
        // your code 
    });
});
```

UPDATE :

I used the advice that Floris offered below, which worked except that that panel switcher no longer worked.  Since this was meant to be in a Shopidy page, I tried adding the code that had been commented out into the head (an include) and it is now working.

Comment: In your fiddle, what is "jcps"? It is undefined.

Comment: That comes from the code I used from this plugin: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-content-panel-switcher/

Answer (score 0):

I forked your jsFiddle and made it work: http://jsfiddle.net/n6tFW/

You really only need one $(document).ready function, not three.

This is missing a closing ":
`$("#one, #two, #three, #four)`

So that should be:
`$("#one, #two, #three, #four")`

Note that I commented out this line:
`jcps.fader(300, '#switcher-panel');`

I assume that is some library you have in your code which jsFiddle didn't have. It caused the script to break there.

Over here, you are closing the $(document).ready function too soon:

```
$('#faq-group a').click(function(){
    $('#faq-group  a').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
}); //Closes the $(document).ready function, but you don't want to do that yet!
```

And then, all that is left is to add an extra `});` to the end:

```
$('#faq-1-1').click(function() {
$('#faq-1-1-hide').slideToggle('slow', function() {

});
});
});
```

That brings the total of your JS code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#one, #two, #three, #four").on('click', function() {
        $('[class$="-dropdown"]').not('.'+this.id.replace('nav','')+'-dropdown').slideUp();
        $('.'+this.id.replace('nav','')+'-dropdown').slideToggle(1000);
    });

    //jcps.fader(300, '#switcher-panel');

    $('#media-side-nav ul li a').click(function() {
        $('#media-side-nav ul li a').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });

    $('#faq-group a').click(function() {
        $('#faq-group a').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });

    $('#faq-1-1').click(function() {
        $('#faq-1-1-hide').slideToggle('slow', function() {

        });
    });
});
```

**So yeah, the real meat and potatoes of this problem is that you need to indent your code properly. You would catch mistakes like these instantly!** And the missing " is just a small mistake, no problem!

Answer (score 0):

You have been using the id `faq-group` several times. This is *not valid HTML*. Put the divs in a class of that name then it should work!